# Does it help to mark ivars in .m files private?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

If I'm declaring an ivar in a `.m` file, either in an `@implementation` block or in a class extension, is there any benefit to marking it `@private`?

It seems that whether or not they are private, a compiler error is generated. However, according to Apple, accessing private variables causes a [link error](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-SW1/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-SW1). So it does seem that there's an advantage to declaring them `@private`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance variables declared in the `@interface` have a default class of `@protected`.  Declarations in the `@implementation` are private.  An explicit `@private` attribute is unnecessary in the latter case.

Comment: Mind sharing a link to a reference that says that ivars declared in @implementation blocks are private? Also, what about the case of an ivar declared in a class extension in a .m file — any benefit to making them private?

Comment: Documentation?  I actually tried it.  It's not hard to set up a test case.

Comment: Variables declared in an extension are not visible to subclasses.

Comment: What about the link error mentioned in my question?

Comment: Your link is to an 8 year old document.  It's irrelevant.  Why don't you experiment yourself and see what works and what doesn't?  The `@public`, `@private` and `@protected` directives are pretty much obsolete, as no one outside the class should be referencing an instance variable.

Comment: It's fine if you don't want to say more, but saying that access qualifiers are obsolete is wrong — they are there precisely to prevent unintended access.